# CAB Uninstaller fails to remove running program

Tags: windows-mobile, uninstallation

I maintain a .NET 3.5 CF application that runs on Window Mobile 6. Is there any way to kill the app's process when the UNINSTALLER runs?

Currently, if the user does not "properly" exit the software before attempting to uninstall it from Settings > Remove Programs (so that the process is still running), they get an error saying the software could not be properly uninstalled.

I would like to have the uninstaller to kill the running process during the uninstall to prevent this. But I can't seem to find a way to manipulate the Uninstall process at all (custom actions, etc).

We're using a SmartDevice Setup installer project for the installation, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supports the use of a setup dll. This DLL has to implement 4 callbacks. The Windows CE/Mobile installer/uninstaller will invoke thos 4 callbacks during install and uninstall.

The install callbacks are InstallInit and InstallExit and the uninstall callbacks are UninstallInit and UninstallExit. The header ce_setup.h coming with the Windows CE/Mobile SDKs is to be used.

I recommend to use Uninstall_Init and in there kill the executable to be uninstalled.

A Code sample for a possible kill function is at https://github.com/hjgode/win-mobile-code/blob/master/iKill2/locktaskbar.h, see KillExeWindow.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx